# Flutter check internet connection on device B from device A

Tags: flutter, firebase, websocket, push-notification

i'm building a chat application and i'm currently facing some issues on displaying the single tick i.e single grey tick will be shown if

1 / the reciever is not logged in on the application

2 / the reciever phone is closed

3 / the reciever has no internet connection

Any idea how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

this blog post will give you a good start point [take a look](https://frestufhere.blogspot.com/2022/12/Flutter%20Chat%20App%20Implementing%20Delivery%20Status%20Tracking.html)